# My bose AE2w Headphones connect but not visible in sound settings sometimes but overall not good sound quality

Tags: sound, headphones

My headphones work with my ipad and iphone. It's just that on my Mac Book Pro mid 2012 13 inch (9,2) the sound quality is low on Ubuntu and better on my other devices. Please help, I've tried everything. I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Bose AE2w Headphones runs in 2 different modes:

1. Telephony Duplex (HSP/HFP) for 2 ways comunication. (Mic and
   speakers)
2. High Fidelity Playback (A2DP) for 1 way comunication.
   (speakers only but in high quality)

Ubuntu does not currently know how to switch between the different modes it seems. However you can manualy change them using the commandline with 2 commands:

To list all bluetooth id's, open terminal and type:

`pactl list cards short`

To set the desired profile, open terminal and type:

`pactl set-card-profile X a2dp` (where X is the ID you just found)

This was tested on Ubuntu 15.04 64bit desktop